# Variable is changed to default value though I have assigned a value to it inside subscribe function

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am using **subject** which is emitting a value from one component. Then I subscribed it in another component and assigned it to a variable. The problem that I am facing is when I am printing the variable inside the subscribe function I'm able to see the value whereas It's showing default value when I am trying to print outside the subscribe function.

Can somebody explain  the reason for this issue

**Code**

**firstComponent**

```
  this.dataService.activateMenusTab.next(false);
```

**secondComponent**

```
this.isMediaTabActive = true;
 this.dataService.activateMenusTab.subscribe((res) => {
      this.isMediaTabActive = res;
      console.log(this.isMediaTabActive);//printing false
    });
    console.log(this.isMediaTabActive);//printing true
```

Comment: When you send an email, can you see the response from the receiver immediately after you've clicked the send button? No. The response is only visible later, when the receiver has read the email, and responded. Same here. That's why the service returns an Observable: to let you subscribe, in order to notify you when the response is finally available, long after the console.log() has been executed.

Comment: In order to use the updated value, you have to do the processing inside of the `subscribe` callback.

Answer (score 2):

It's nothing but **Sync and Async**. That's why you are getting true as a value of `this.isMediaTabActive` outside the **subscribe**.

In the example, the `this.isMediaTabActive = true;` will be executed while the `this.dataService.activateMenusTab` is call to the service which will executed asynchronously. That is, the query will be processed in the background, while your program is doing other things, and once the query data is ready, you will do whatever you want with it.

> Below I have mentioned the sequence of the line that will be executed.

```
1.    this.isMediaTabActive = true;
2.    this.dataService.activateMenusTab.subscribe((res) => {
4.       this.isMediaTabActive = res;
5.       console.log(this.isMediaTabActive);//printing false
      });
3.        console.log(this.isMediaTabActive);//printing true
```

For more info: [Sync vs Async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748175/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-execution-what-does-it-really-mean)

Comment: So What do I need to do so that after the subscribe function, The variable should have a value that I have set inside the subscribe

Comment: No, you can't. The console.log statement after the subscribe will print the global value only as I already said in the answer. One patchy way to handle this is to make a function which will run on a set of an interval. And which checks for value change of this.isMediaTabActive.

Comment: Ya I have solved the issue by removing subject and created a variable in service class and assigining value to it in one component and using it in another component  and making it synchronous